# Python : write to serial port as /x06

Tags: python, pyserial

I need to write 06 as /x06 to serial port to give an acknowledement for a machine, my code is given below, what is the correction needed

```
import time 
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM1',baudrate=9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1)
counter=0

while 1:
    ser.write('06')
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1
    x=ser.readline()
    print x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
ser.write("06".encode())
```

Here's the [docs](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write).

Comment: when i did "06".encode() shows as output 2 not generating \x06

Comment: That should mean it sent 2 bytes to serial port. Try sending longer string.

Comment: i sent it as ser.write("\x06".encode()) and worked... thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `'06'` to `'\x06'`.